# What method does Python call when I access an attribute of a class via the class name?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know *accessing the attributes of Foo through an instance* will call the `__getattribute__()` method, but what if I *access this attribute directly through the class*? If a function is called, I want to set a breakpoint in it so that the breakpoint can be triggered when accessing this property through a class in my project.

I have tried to set breakpoint in magic method `__getattribute__()`, but nothing hapened.

```py
class Foo:
    age = 18


print(Foo.age)  # I am curious what method is called
```

Comment: Interesting [article](https://medium.com/stepping-through-the-cpython-interpreter/how-does-attribute-access-work-d19371898fee)

Comment: `__dict__` isn't a method; the instance dict is directly available with this name, you don't call it.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Technically `__dict__` is a descriptor which provides the instance dict.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I mistakenly thought `__dict__` is also a magic method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything in Python is an object and everything has a `type` that determines the object's behavior. This also holds for class objects. You can check `type(Foo)`:

```py
>>> type(Foo)
<class 'type'>
```

You can customize the type of a class by providing a custom `metaclass`. This metaclass is then responsible for attribute access on the class object:

```py
class MyMeta(type):
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        print(f'__getattribute__({self!r}, {name!r})')
        return super().__getattribute__(name)


class Foo(metaclass=MyMeta):
    age = 18


print(Foo.age)
```

and the output is:

```
__getattribute__(<class '__main__.Foo'>, 'age')
18
```

Comment: Without decoration, you would want to set the breakpoint in `type.__getattribute__`, but at least in the reference C implementation, `type` is implemented in C and there is nothing exposed where you could set such a breakpoint with pdb.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel You mean without using a custom metaclass? I'm not too familiar with the C API but I would be surprised if it exposed something to set a breakpoint in `type.__getattribute__`. Seems like a rare use case.

Comment: You would have to have a debug build of Python, compiled with the same IDE you're using to set the breakpoint, and with known compilation settings, I imagine.

Comment: In this case, could I override the `__getattribute__` return in `Foo`? I tried the same structure as above, but changed to simply `return 42` in `MyMeta.__getattribute__`. However if I call `Foo.age` I still get 18, not 42.

Comment: @tigerninjaman You mean you replaced `return super().__getattribute__(name)` with `return 42`? In that case `Foo.age` should return `42` and it works for me.

Comment: I must have had something off, restarting my environment worked. Obviously a hard return isn't something you would ever do, since it would ruin calls to class functions, but it was useful to help me understand `__getattribute__`. Thanks!